# iOS Horizontal Bar Graph in Core Plot showing two values

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have worked with Bar graphs with Core Plot, but i couldn't find a way to get a horizontal bar chart containing bars with multiple values. Is there a way to do it in Core Plot?

Here is an image of what i want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with stacked bar plots. Make one bar plot for each section and set `barBasesVary` to `YES` for each one. This causes the plot to query the datasource for an additional field called `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase` for each bar. Use this to set the lower edge of the bar.

The "Vertical Bar Chart" in the *Plot Gallery* example app demonstrates this technique.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a really old post. But I have recently created a library which is creating horizontal bars from given values. It's written in Swift and maybe someone can use this in future projects.

https://github.com/prine/ROStorageBar